# Web site fails to deploy

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I have created a new ASP.NET5 web site, using VS2015 CE, and I can't get it to deploy to an IIS7.5 server.

I can deploy older projects to this server.

When I use the Publish Web wizard, the Connection tab is correctly configured (Validate Connection shows success).  Pressing "Start Preview" on the Preview Tab shows the correct list of files to be sent to the server.

This suggests to me that VS can communicate successfully with WebDeploy on the server.

When I press Publish, I get:

```
Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer (blah blah blah)
/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I have read https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html and followed all the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the package manually using MSDeploy.exe with the `-verbose` flag to try to get more details about the error.

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=WebApplication7.zip -dest:manifest=WebApplication7.DestManifest.xml
```

There is a section at the bottom of the following post with full instructions on deploying a package manually.

[The Anatomy of a WebDeploy Package](http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/)

Comment: Running with -verbose doesn't give any further information.